# Cached textmodules in smartforms

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I'm using textmodules for our footer in smartforms. If I change something in those modules and transport it, the change won't take effect on the form.

If I open the text via transaction `Smartforms` everything is correct.

Is there any cache I need to clean up?

Answer (score 0):

You should re-generate form to get it updated

[image]